# Android Firebase Retrieve Realtime Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to get data from the database.

Code:

```
mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User")mDatabaseUsers.orderByChild("name").startAt("m");
    mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true); mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);

                        String name = map.get("name");

                        Toast.makeText(AddFriendActivity.this,nick.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

I want to get all users with the letter m!

How does is work?
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So you'll need to loop over the results in `dataSnapshot`:

```
mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(userSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Also see the brief example in the [Firebase documentation on using a `value` event to get a list of results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Comment: Thank you! I have another question. How can I check the database to see, if the name does not exist? Because my mobile phone crasht!

Comment: That topic has been covered quite a few times before. Have a look at some of the top results here: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+unique+username